# Difference between Arcore and arcore android sdk in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

I have been learning AR-Core in unity these days, Quite often I find myself looking into documentation and tutorials. But one thing that confuses me is that some of those tutorials use a sdk for AR-core while others download Ar-foundation and Ar-Core/Ar-kit from package manager when installing AR-core in Unity.

I wanted to ask about what is the difference between these 2? Are they the same? Because sdk's usually have version 1.X.X while AR-foundation package has version up-to 4.X.X.

Also are there certain dependencies that are only available in sdk or vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AR Foundation includes core features from multiple Augmented Reality frameworks such as ARKit, ARCore, Magic Leap and HoloLens, but also includes unique Unity features (like the AR Session/Plane).

Instead of having to code twice, AR Foundation allows you to do it just once.

So directly asking your questions:

> Are they the same?(AR-Foundation & AR-Core/Kit)

No. AR-Foundation INCLUDES the other two, but they two do not include the whole capability of AR-Foundation.

> There certain dependencies that are only available in sdk or vice
> versa?

Not quite sure, but as far as they aren't the same, this could be a solid possibility.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I also wanted to know what is the difference if you import the ARCore sdk as package and importing AR-Foundation and Arcor from package manager? Do they have different user experience? (like: AR-Foundation supports planes etc.)

Comment: I recommend you tocuse package manager as Unity can handle dependencies better, but if you simply import packages will work anyway. Keep in mind that AR foundation also needs those external packages, more information about instalation and package dependencies here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.arfoundation@4.1/manual/index.html .Remember to Mark this answer as correct (if It is)